# Composer with Koseven (Kohana)

Tags: php, kohana-3.3

I'm developing an application where I started using Kohana and now Koseven, and I need to use an api that was available in the composer, I followed the steps to download the files I created a folder to sell inside the application, and put in the bootstrap.php code to call the autoload of the composer.
But after doing this when trying to use a class of this api error of "class not found" occurs.
I do not know what else to do, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `composer` with Kohana or Koseven, you need to call `composer`'s autoloader from within `bootstrap.php`.

After `Kohana::modules($modules);` and before  `Route::set`, insert the following code:

```
/**
 * Autoload composer libraries
 *
 */
require APPPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

This assumes your `composer install` command is run the from the root of your app, and it uses the default `vendor` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you must add this to your `composer.json`. (Check inc composer doc.) I don't know, because in `modules` directory I have second instance.

```
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "modules/{$name}/": ["type:kohana-module"]
    }
},
```

And enable module `composer` as first:

```
Kohana::modules(array(
    'composer'   => MODPATH.'composer',       // 
    'auth'       => MODPATH.'auth',       // Basic authentication
    'cache'      => MODPATH.'cache',      // Caching with multiple backends
```

It works for me ko3

Comment: It's best practice to use composer at the top level, instead of as a module.